# How to get an element from an ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>?

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, arraylist

I have an arraylist of arraylists having string[]s i.e.,

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> arraymain = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String[]> arraysub = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now, adding the elements to arraysub,

```
arraysub.add(new String[]{"vary","unite"});
arraysub.add(new String[]{"new","old"});
```

I tried:

```
arraymain.get(0).get(0)[1];
```

But I'm getting an error : Array type expected; found 'java.lang.Object'
How can I now retrieve the data(the string stored in the string[])?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the type of the inner ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String[]>> arraymain = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String[]> arraysub = new ArrayList<>();
```

This way `arraymain.get(0).get(0)` will return a `String[]` instead of an `Object`.

It would be even better if you declare the variables as `List`s, instead of forcing a specific `List` implementation:

```
List<List<String[]>> arraymain = new ArrayList<>();
List<String[]> arraysub = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Oh! I see. I need to declare the Type of sub arraylist as well in the main array itself. That was quite simple. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

But arraymain accepts arraylists of type string array only, If u want to store different arraylists of different array types in arraymain then this will be the solution:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object[]>> arraymain = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object[]>>();
ArrayList<Object[]> arraysub = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
arraysub.add(new String[]{"kk"});
arraymain.add(arraysub);
ArrayList<Object[]> arraysub2 = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
arraysub2.add(new Integer[]{1,2});
arraymain.add(arraysub2);
```

Comment: Thank you. Though not now, this is useful to know. I’ll keep this in mind. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> outer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> inner = new ArrayList();

    inner.add("ABC");
    inner.add("XYZ");
    inner.add("CDF");

    outer.add(inner);

    ArrayList<String> orderList = outer.get(0);
    String first = orderList.get(0);
    String second = orderList.get(1);
    String third = orderList.get(2);

    System.out.println("FirstValue: "+first);
    System.out.println("SecondValue: "+second);
    System.out.println("ThirdValue: "+third);
```